# Whats a good ETH notary service since BTC based OP_RETRUN txns are taboo?

Tags: blockchain

I want to notarize a `SHA256` hash of a document I have.  Before ETH I would have used a BTC `OP_RETURN` transaction service.  Since BTC is trying to reduce notary spam, what would be a good ETH notary service that people might recommend that the ETH community doesn't frown upon?

- [A look at OP_RETURN and whether embedding arbitrary data into Bitcoin’s blockchain is spam](https://www.theblockcrypto.com/2019/01/09/a-look-at-op_return-and-whether-embedding-arbitrary-data-into-bitcoins-blockchain-is-spam/)

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way I found was to just include the data I want notarized in a $0 transaction to myself in the `data` field.  This is usually used for Contracts, but technically anything can get put in there.

I realize that at some time in the future, the ETH blockchain may choose to prune these bits of data away, but for my immediate need, it will fit the bill...